# expanding divs and scrolling

Tags: javascript

I have a few long descriptions. On page load, I hide the long description and instead I truncate it to show the short description. The way I do this is to toggle the description divs.

They look like this:

hello world! my name is **more**

hello world! my name is **more**

hello world! my name is **more**

When you click on **more**, it will expand the description. After it expands, it will have a **less** that brings it back to short form.

The problem is that if the description is long enough, once you click less, you can no longer see the description (because you have scrolled it offscreen.

What I want it to do when the user click **less** is this:

When the **less** is showing, the user is able to see what is below that description. So everything below should stay in place, while everything above the description we clicked slides into view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jQuery slideUp, slideDown, slideToggle, hide, show. There are tons of way to do it.

Comment: how do you keep track of the location of the description below so that stays in place?

Comment: actually im sure thats not what I want. I dont need animation.

Comment: The extra text is already there. You just decide how much you want to hide and just show/hide it.